# Unicode string and FreeHGlobal issue?

Tags: c#, c++, exception, dll, interop

I tested the code from Stack Overflow question *[Marshaling unmanaged char** to managed string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914999/marshaling-unmanaged-char-to-managed-string-problem)*, and it works well.

I tried to convert it to Unicode, and then I start getting "The handle is invalid". Why?

My modified code:

```
_declspec(dllexport) void TestArray(wchar_t** OutBuff, int Count, int MaxLength)
{
    for(int i=0; i<Count; i++)
    {
        wchar_t buff[25];
        _itow(i, buff, 10);
        wcsncpy(OutBuff[i], buff, MaxLength);
    }
}
```

And the C# wrapper:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("Native.dll", EntryPoint = "?TestArray@@YAXPAPA_WHH@Z", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void TestArray([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    IntPtr[] OutBuff, int Count, int MaxLength);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 10;
        int maxLen = 50;
        IntPtr[] buffer = new IntPtr[maxLen];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            buffer[i] = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(maxLen);

        TestArray(buffer, count, maxLen);

        string[] output = new string[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            output[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(buffer[i]);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer[i]); // Crash is here, when count is 1.
            Console.WriteLine(output[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lucky to get the Windows heap manager to catch the bug, you must be using Vista or Windows 7.  It is a subtle one and would have been easily missed if you hadn't used wcsncpy().  The problem is that you allocated maxLen *bytes* for the string.  But you need to allocate maxLen *characters*.  Not the same thing when you use Unicode strings, one character is two bytes.  You also got the buffer allocation wrong.  Fix:

```
        IntPtr[] buffer = new IntPtr[count];   // NOTE: not maxLen
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
            buffer[i] = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(maxLen * sizeof(Char));
```

The heap corruption occurs because of the way wcsncpy() works.  If fills the remainder of the buffer with zeros, unlike wcscpy_s().  Since your buffer is too small, that overwrites and corrupts the heap.  Windows stepped in when it noticed that the internal heap structure was compromised.

Answer (score 0):

You passed an `IntPtr` array and modified it directly in the native function (treating it as pointer-to-pointer). Since `IntPtr` is from the [managed world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code), direct modification has corrupted it - and hence the handle is invalid.

Comment: Well, it worked for the ANSI version. If direct modification can cause corruption, how to rewrite the code to pass dynamic array of strings betwwen the languages?